# Link between address and Twitter handle with DirectAuth

Tags: privacy, kukai

If I have an account on Kukai wallet using [DirectAuth](https://docs.kukai.app/learn-kukai/direct-auth) with my Twitter handle,

1. Would someone who knows my Twitter handle be able to deduce my address and therefore see my balance?
2. Would someone who knows my address be able to get my Twitter handle? (assuming if answer to question 1 is Yes that he does not brute-force all plausible handles)